# Error when trying to connect to google finance Python

Tags: python, pandas-datareader

I am able to connect to yahoo finance using datareader but am having issues connecting to other APIs such as google finance and I cannot figure out why.

I am using the following code:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 27)
end = datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 7)
f = web.DataReader('F', 'google', start, end)
f.ix['2017-11-04']
```

And get the following error message:

RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL: http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=F&startdate=Sep+27%2C+2017&enddate=Nov+07%2C+2017&output=csv

Any suggestions would be helpful as I could not find anything online about this.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the csv file, you will see that there is no data for "2017-11-04", hence the error.

The codes would work for another date, such as "2017-11-03", which is in the csv. Here is the output:

```
Open            12.41
High            12.46
Low             12.32
Close           12.36
Volume    33220261.00
Name: 2017-11-03 00:00:00, dtype: float64
```

Google Finance API does not cover every day. It frequently misses a day or two.

Comment: @YingSquared- I tried that and i am still getting the same error message. When I copy and paste the URL, generate the excel file, and open it, the data is all there, but python seem to be having trouble reading the URL. raise RemoteDataError('Unable to read URL: {0}'.format(url))

RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL: http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=F&startdate=Sep+27%2C+2017&enddate=Nov+07%2C+2017&output=csv